# How can I build "Class::function()->function($parm)->function($parm);" methods in PHP and how it works?

Tags: php, laravel

I am wondering in Some of PHP frameworks uses methods like
`Class::function()->function($parm)->function($parm);` 
for an example in Laravel 
`DB::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->value('email');`

How these methods are internally working?

How can I build such Kind of method of my own?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foo::function()->function Two() its a static call to a public function which returning a new instance.

```
Class foo{
      Public static function (){
            Return new class bar();
       }

Class bar{
     Public function functionTwo(){
         //Some code
     }
```

Keep in mind that this it is not always good because is violoting the Law of demeter https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter